# Hardware-only 'Undefined' database error on openDatabase in Cordova 2.5 on Android - only for first attempt

Tags: android, cordova, undefined, opendatabase

Just updated my android app to Cordova 2.5 and, although it works beautifully in the emulator, it has developed a problem on my HTC desire such that I get a  'undefined' databse error when I try

```
db = window.openDatabase("ProblemDirectoryDB", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 100000);
```

However, if I open the same page a second time, it works fine and from then on, even after a forced stop and restart. I can recreate the error by deleting the application's data. The relevant code is below. Any help/thoughts very gratefully received.

```
var db;
var dbCreated = false;

function onBodyLoad(){
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
$.mobile.loadingMessage = "Loading...";
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
if (!window.device){
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } 
else {
    onDeviceReady();
    }
}

function onDeviceReady() {
db = window.openDatabase("ProblemDirectoryDB", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 100000);
    if (dbCreated){
        db.transaction(getProblems, read_transaction_error);
        }
    else{
        db.transaction(populateDB, create_transaction_error, populateDB_success);
        }
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}

function populateDB_success() {
dbCreated = true;
    db.transaction(getProblems, transaction_error);
}

function create_transaction_error(tx, error) {
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    alert("Create Database Error: " + error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievably, after hours and hours and a near-total rewrite, I finally spotted the `100000` bytes `size` parameter in my `window.openDatabase` call - my DB now exceeds 256K so simply changing it to `300000` appears to have solved my problem!!
No wonder no-one else seems to have had the same problem - no-one else has been stupid enough not to notice the size parameter! Although quite why it worked on the emulator and on second and successive opens on the hardware, I don't know. Anyway, problem solved.